# Adding Click function to input type image in php giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make an `onClick` function from input type image. Here is the code

```
<td>
    <?php if($ring[ "bandPaths"] !='' ) echo '
<input id="bandImage" type="image" src="http://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/vowstore/bands/'. $ring[ 'bandPaths'] . '" onClick="openGallery('.$ring[ 'bandPaths']. ');" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-left: 10px;">
'; ?>
</td>

<script>
    function openGallery(var url) {
        $.colorbox({
            width: "80%",
            height: "80%",
            iframe: true,
            href: "/pagetoopen.html"
        });
    }
</script>
```

i get the error `openGallery is not defined`. What wrong am i doing?

Comment: Move your `<script>` into your `<head>`, before the PHP.

Comment: Can you give us a live demo?

Comment: @MariM it is still the same

Comment: `var url` isn't valid in the argument list, it should just be `url`. But the function doesn't use its argument.

Comment: What is the type of `$ring['bandPaths']`? If it's a string, you need to put quotes around it in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Don't move script into the head. It should be in the footer.

Comment: how can i give live demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript syntax is invalid, you should be getting a syntax error in the console. It should be:

```
function openGallery(url)
{    
  $.colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, href:"/pagetoopen.html"});
}
```

`var` is only used to declare local variables in the function body. Function arguments are automatically declared as local, so the `var` keyword is not used there.

Comment: That actually did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the string you are passing through to the function:

```
<td>
<?php if($ring["bandPaths"] != '') 
echo '<input id="bandImage" type="image" src="http://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/vowstore/bands/'.  $ring['bandPaths'] .'" onClick="openGallery(\''.$ring['bandPaths'].'\');" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-left: 10px;">'; ?>
</td>
```

Notice the \' wrapping the string.